# Understand log scale and actually taking np.log of a data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, natural-logarithm

I am currently working up some experimental data and am having a hard time understanding whether I should be doing a log scale or actually applying np.log onto the data.

#### Here is the plot I have made.

[image]

Blue represents using `plt.yscale('log')`, whereas the orange is creating a new column and applying `np.log` onto the data.

#### My question

Why are their magnitudes so different? Which is correct? and if using `plt.yscale('log')` is the optimal way to do it, is there a way I can get those values as I need to do a curve fit after?

Thanks in advance for anyone that can provide some answers!

#### edit(1)

I understand that `plt.yscale('log')` is in base 10 and `np.log` refers to the natural log. I have tried using `np.log10` on the data instead and it gives a smaller value that does not correspond to using a log scale.

Comment: @AsishM. thanks for the comment! I gave `np.log10` a try and it is giving a smaller value than if I did `np.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is getting log-ified but "pointing"? in the wrong direction.

Consider this toy data

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)[:-1]
y = np.log(1-x) + 5
```

Then we plot

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

If I log scale it:
It's just more exaggerated

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

You need to point your data the other direction like normal log data

```
plt.plot(-x, y)
```

[image]

But you also have to make sure the data is positive or ... you know ... logs and stuff `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
plt.plot(-x + 1, y)
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]